# Visiting vertices on a graph using DFS and BFS

Tags: graphs, graph-traversal, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

[image: .]

I have this graph that I created and am wondering how DFS and BFS would work on something like this. I made this graph undirected and am going off the premise that if possible, a vertex should be visited in numerical order

Comment: Implement the algorithms and run them. You don't need us for that.

Comment: Please credit the original source of all copied material.  I suspect this came from somewhere; where?  See  https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/would-depth-first-search-breadth-first-search-undirected-graph-visited-numerical-order-q86652196